# How to iterate over a slice and build one string from the output\

Tags: string, loops, go

How would I iterate over a slice and build a new single string from the output, then return that string in a function?

For example if I wanted to read a slice and add an index to each item, then put the new changes in a single string and return it in a function:

```
func buildString() string {
  strSlice := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
  for index, element := range strSlice{
  fmt.Println(index, "===", element)

  bigString := append(strSlice, fmt.Prinln(index, "===", element)
  }

return bigString
}
```

Comment: You have a number of very basic errors. I recommend you take the [tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) to learn the language. And remember to read the docs for the packages you use (eg: [fmt](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully agree with [Marc's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69406465/how-to-iterate-over-a-slice-and-build-one-string-from-the-output-in-golang#comment122675849_69406465), but just for completeness, the following would be a possible solution to what you are trying to accomplish:

```
func buildString(strSlice []string) string {
    var bigString string
    for index, element := range strSlice {
        bigString += fmt.Sprintf("%d === %s\n", index, element)
    }

    return bigString
}

func main() {
    strSlice := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
    result := buildString(strSlice)

    fmt.Print(result)
}
```

But please, take the Tour of Go that Marc recommended to you.

Comment: Thank you!! And yes I will take a look into golang at the fundamentals for sure!

Answer (score 1):

You may use `strings.Builder`, which is more efficient, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/9akaQfYgqyW):

```
func buildString(a []string) string {
    var sb strings.Builder
    for i, s := range a {
        sb.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(i))
        sb.WriteString(" === ")
        sb.WriteString(s)
        sb.WriteRune('\n')
    }
    return sb.String()
}
```

Benchmark:

```
Benchmark1-8  4203799   252 ns/op   56 B/op  3 allocs/op
Benchmark6-8  5044305   280 ns/op   56 B/op  3 allocs/op
Benchmark4-8  4332459   319 ns/op   72 B/op  3 allocs/op
Benchmark5-8  2792514   371 ns/op   56 B/op  3 allocs/op
Benchmark3-8  1000000  1018 ns/op  144 B/op  8 allocs/op
Benchmark2-8  1000000  1109 ns/op  152 B/op  8 allocs/op
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func buildString(a []string) string {
    var sb strings.Builder
    for i, s := range a {
        sb.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(i))
        sb.WriteString(" === ")
        sb.WriteString(s)
        sb.WriteRune('\n')
    }
    return sb.String()
}
func buildString6(a []string) string {
    var sb strings.Builder
    for i, s := range a {
        sb.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(i))
        sb.WriteString(" === ")
        sb.WriteString(s)
        sb.WriteString("\n")
    }
    return sb.String()
}
func buildString5(a []string) string {
    var sb strings.Builder
    for i, s := range a {
        sb.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(i))
        sb.WriteString(" === " + s + "\n")
    }
    return sb.String()
}

func buildString4(a []string) string {
    var sb strings.Builder
    b := make([]byte, 0, 10)
    for i, s := range a {
        b = strconv.AppendInt(b[:0], int64(i), 10)
        b = append(b, " === "...)
        b = append(b, s...)
        b = append(b, '\n')
        sb.WriteString(string(b))
    }
    return sb.String()
}

func buildString3(a []string) string {
    var sb strings.Builder
    for i, s := range a {
        sb.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%d === %s\n", i, s))
    }
    return sb.String()
}

func buildString2(strSlice []string) string {
    var bigString string
    for index, element := range strSlice {
        bigString += fmt.Sprintf("%d === %s\n", index, element)
    }
    return bigString
}

func Benchmark1(b *testing.B) {
    strSlice := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = buildString(strSlice)
    }
}

func Benchmark2(b *testing.B) {
    strSlice := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = buildString2(strSlice)
    }
}

func Benchmark3(b *testing.B) {
    strSlice := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = buildString3(strSlice)
    }
}

func Benchmark4(b *testing.B) {
    strSlice := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = buildString4(strSlice)
    }
}

func Benchmark5(b *testing.B) {
    strSlice := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = buildString5(strSlice)
    }
}

func Benchmark6(b *testing.B) {
    strSlice := []string{"one", "two", "three"}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = buildString6(strSlice)
    }
}
```

go version go1.17.1